# Calling BCL functions with tuple arguments in F#

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

From what I've read, and if I am not mistaken, it seems that any BCL method receives its arguments as a tuple in F#. So I was wondering if instead of having

```
let rndNumber= rng.Next(-10, 10)
```

I could have something along the lines of

```
let range = (-10, 10)
let rndNumber = rng.Next range
```

*the full code is the following:*

```
open System
let rng = new Random()
let range = (-10, 10)
let rndNumber = rng.Next range
```

*and the error I'm getting is*

```
This expression was expected to have type
    int    
but here has type
    int * int
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
let rndNumber = range |> rng.Next
```

I think the lack of type information at the point of the method call is causing it to default to the first overload (accepting int). If you pipe your argument to it, it knows which overload you want.

Comment: Stare at it until it looks beautiful--it's the F# way. :-) Piping is necessary all over the place because of top-to-bottom/left-to-right type inference.

Comment: Yes, I already had came to the conclusion that F# is everything but pretty (at least in comparison with haskell). Oh well, we can't have it all.. Btw, isn't there any other way of giving the clue to the compiler?

Comment: Yes, you can do `let rndNumber = (rng.Next : int * int -> int) range` instead.

Answer (score 7):

You could have a .NET method overload that takes a single argument of type `System.Tuple` as well, which complicates matters.

In general, F# looks at the call site of the method, and syntactically determines which overloads to try.  When you call `o.M aTupleVar` F# tries to find a method taking a single argument (that is a tuple), as opposed to multiple arguments.

The "piping" workaround Daniel suggested works because there is no syntactic call to a method, so F# just resolves `rng.Next` to the overload group of methods with that name, and resolves the call later.

That said, there is almost never a reason in practice to do this.  If you're going to call a .NET method, do it directly with `o.M(arg1,arg2)`, there is rarely a need/desire to create a tuple first.